# emacs lisp: how to add to link/hyperlink to another file just like that in *H e l p*

Tags: emacs, elisp

we can get help with "C-h ..." and emacs show a *Help* buffer,and jump to other place with the link . How can I make something like that with elisp, link to another buffer or show something else?

Comment: thanks for "button" and "clickable text"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The builtin *Button* package provides a convenient way.  For example,

```
(require 'button)
(insert-button "foo" 'action (lambda (x) (find-file user-init-file)))
```

will insert a button/link labeled "foo" that when activated (by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while point is over the label or middle clicking) will bring up the init file.

Here is another example that mimics a www link,

```
(insert-button "fsf"
               'action (lambda (x) (browse-url (button-get x 'url)))
               'url "http://www.fsf.org")
```

See *Elisp Reference Manual [38.17 Buttons](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buttons.html)*.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at "clickable text"

Read **[this](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Clickable-Text.html)** for more explanation.

Or **[this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Handling-links.html)** if you are going to be using org-mode.